# Error on requireing CURL PHP extension with integrating Google OAuth with PHP on Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl, google-oauth

I am developing an application that requires integration with Google APIs Client Library for PHP. I am running on LAMP stack on Ubuntu. I have the application up and running on my local host. When I integrate the code from [Google API PHP client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/) I get the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Google CurlIO client requires the CURL PHP extension

I am unable to find help in any other forum. Can someone please point me to a solution to this. I suspect this could be somehow related to me developing and running the application in my local folder instead of var/www. I have added a file called mysite and pointing Apache to run from a local folder though.

Comment: Install **php5-curl** package from synaptic package manager.

Answer (score 6):

**CURL PHP**  extension is not installed on your **PHP module of Apache** server. You have to install it using terminal

Open Terminal (**CTRL + ALT + T**) and do the following command :

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

**php5-curl** will be automatically downloaded and installed. After Installation, Reload **Apache2** Server :

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for clarification if you are using PHP7/Any PHP version you can simply execute

```
sudo apt-get install php-curl
```

this will download the appropriate extensions for your installed PHP,

In My case it downloaded `php7.2 curl`